# Are ASP.NET 4.6 and ASP.NET 5 both MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm a little bit confused about what is what! I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 and when I'm going to start a new project I have to select a template. There are ASP.NET 4.6 templates like `Empty` and `MVC`, but then there are also options within ASP.NET 5 like `Web Application` template.

My question is: are both(ASP.NET 4.6 & ASP.NET 5) a MVC 5 project and how do I know I'm creating a MVC 5 project?

Comment: MVC Templates for ASP.NET 5 in Visual Studio are MVC 6

Comment: @haim770 OK! Thanks for the info! So an ASP.NET 4.6 is MVC 5 then?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-asp-net-4-6-and-asp-net-5-beta-5-in-visual-studio-2015-release.aspx check this out